# 2006 Pontiac G6 GTP 3.9l A/C won't turn on

Tags: ac, pontiac, g6

About a month ago, I added freon to my a/c low pressure port. I followed the instructions carefully making sure that I didn't run into the red on the gauge. About 2 weeks later, my A/C started responding abnormally. Sporadically, it would barely turn on, or be slow to increase the blower speed. Literally, I could turn it on high and it would blow as if it were on low. Now my a/c won't turn on at all. I don't believe the compressor is engaging either. Usually you can feel the difference. Here's the kicker, I disconnected my battery because I was going away on a week cruise. When I came back, I connected my battery and my a/c worked as long as my car stayed on. I mean it blew like it was brand new. However, the moment the car was turned off and crunk back up, my a/c was dead. Any ideas of what's causing the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You need a scanner that can talk to the Body Control Module to solve it.